# Cannot Use the Value of an Item in SQL Database

Tags: python, sql, database

I Have this example of sql database. I want to use a certain item from the database in math calculation but I can't because the value looks like this: (25.0,) instead of just 25.0. Please see the attached picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRPRc.jpg

```
import sqlite3
#Create the database:
connection = sqlite3.connect('DataBase.db')
c = connection.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (name TEXT,age NUMBER)')
c.execute("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('Jhon',25)")
#Pull out the value:
c.execute('SELECT age FROM table1')
data =c.fetchall()
print(data[0])
#simple math calculation:
r=data[0]+1
print(r)
```

Comment: Please read the manual. The manual tells you what `fetchall()` returns, and how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Python's [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the specification for most DB-APIs including `sqlite3`, [`fetchall`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchall) returns a sequence of sequences, usually list of tuples. Therefore, to retrieve the single value in first column to do arithmetic, index the return twice: for specific row and then specific position in row.

```
data = c.fetchall()
data[0][0]
```

Alternatively, [`fetchone`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) returns a single row, either first or next row, in resultset, so simply index once: the position in single row.

```
data = c.fetchone()
data[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned data from `fetchall` always comes back as a list of tuples, even if the tuple only contains 1 value.  Your `data` variable should be:

```
[(25,)]
```

You need to use:

```
print(data[0][0])
r = data[0][0] + 1
print(r)
```